# virtuemart checkout page link

Tags: joomla, checkout, virtuemart

i have used virtuemart latest product module for displaying a product on my home page but now when i click on add to cart it doesn't redirect me to another page. Instead of redirecting to another page it shows the checkout form in content part of my index page....

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying as you say: "when i click on add to cart it doesn't redirect me to another page" but then later you say: "it shows the checkout form", how can it show the checkout page if it doesn't redirect? Which page do you want it to redirect to?

Comment: i mean it doesn't show url like index.php?page=shop.product_details&... it simply shows index.php and all other modules are also visible on that page which should not be there

Comment: Do you have AJAX update turned on? Any chance you can give us a link to the site? If not, can you post the exact URL you are redirected to minus the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sh404sef then please try to use the current latest version of both VM & sh404sef otherwise these compatibility issues frequently comes

Also if the above said not a good solutions then please check whether the URL shown in the address bar of the checkout page shows a get value say: `&ssl_redirect=1` part. if so, then try to please disable the SSL, it may be not useful in the context as your may use the virtue-mart payment gateway to do all the stuff

Comment: i am not using sh404sef at all